# target input in div in div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have a div class tblRow as a wrapper around divs in the class samInput which each hold an input field.

```
<div class='tblRow'>
  <div class='samInput'>
    <input name='somename' type='text'>
  </div>
  <div class='samInput'>
    <input name='somename' type='text'>
  </div>
  <div class='samInput'>
    <input name='somename' type='text'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='tblRow'>
  <div class='samInput'>
    <input name='somename' type='text'>
  </div>
  <div class='samInput'>
    <input name='somename' type='text'>
  </div>
  <div class='samInput'>
    <input name='somename' type='text'>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the values of input fields for the first tblRow.
I've tried

```
$(".sampleRow:first-child > samInput :input").each(function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

and

```
$(".sampleRow:first-child samInput input").each(function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

and

```
$(".sampleRow:first-child input").each(function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

but those don't work

Comment: You know there's no `sampleRow` in that HTML ?

Comment: Don't you want `$(".tblRow:first .samInput :input").each(function(){`

Comment: Yes, your right. I tried:
`(".tblRow:first-child .samInput :input").each(function(){`
but that didn't work either

Comment: @j08691 I'd like to accept this as the answer. Can you put it in the answers and I'll check it?

Comment: Actually I did about 25 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".tblRow:first .samInput :input").each(function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".samInput").eq(0).find("input");
```

[fiddle with code](http://jsfiddle.net/98ngh/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what result you are expecting, but to get input field for the first tblRow, you can try:

```
$(".tblRow:first .samInput:first > input")
```